# Maven Dependency Update

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to import a maven project ,but its unable to update all dependencies related to that and throwing this error,

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.CompatibilityWorkbenchURIConverterImpl
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: did you configure a (reachable) remote maven repository?

Comment: Here is the some suggestion : https://coderanch.com/t/632460/Eclipse. Close eclipse,
Navigate to your "workspace" folder,
Ensure the setting on your OS to view hidden files is turned on,
Identify and delete the .metadata directory,
Restart eclipse,
Import project.